# How to delete a folder that is hidden and has no long and no short name

Tags: windows-vista, virus

How do I delete in Windows Vista a folder that is hidden and has no "long name", and has no "short name" either.  Note that I've already tried to get the short name so I could rename and delete using the command:

```
dir /X /A:H
```

However, there is no short or long name. The folder was created by a virus. I've sanitized the virus except for this folder that won't get deleted.

Comment: to ask the obvious - how do you know its even there?

Comment: Try turning the Hidden attribute off for all files in the folder using wildcards for the filename -- something like `attrib -h *.*`

Comment: You can bypass Windows' name checks by prepending `\\?\` to file paths. So del "\\?\c:\folder\file.ext" This will allow file paths up to 32k long. Most programs won't be able to use such files.

Comment: Is it even possible for a folder to not have a name? As it is my understanding, any folder **needs** to have a name, even if it's a [NBSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)